# How to sand box C/C++ projects which use shared libraries

Tags: c++, c, homebrew

I sometimes dip my toes to Free C/C++ projects that I would like to experiment with.

Nine times out ten this results in a lot of pain to get all the dependencies to work and crucially inevitably this breaks some other project's dependencies so that when I back to that other project I'm again in for an other masochist session.

There has to be a better way but I've not been able to find it.

So have should shared libraries be installed so that only one project 'sees' them?

I'm on Mac OS so I'm really only interested in solutions that work there.

Extra kudos for solutions where I can use homebrew to install those libraries.

Comment: I don't know your exact needs, but it should be possible to build these apps without using shared libraries.

Comment: Did you consider using some package manager like [brew](https://brew.sh/)

Answer (score 3):

When compiling (or rather linking) the application you can specify the -rpath option to tell it where to search for shared libraries at runtime. Including `$ORIGIN` as the first component of the path will cause the search to be done relative to the location of the executable.

This means that you can keep the executables libraries separate from those of other apps.

For example; let's say you install the application in /opt/myapp/bin/ and put its libraries in /opt/myapp/lib/ , then you would set rpath to `$ORIGIN/../lib/` and no matter where you move the /opt/myapp directory to (as long as you move all of it) the application will find its own specific version of the libraries in its own lib/ dir.

That's the Unix solution. On Windows you could simply place the DLLs in the same directory as the executable, since Windows will search there first.